# Зациклить функцию

Tags: jquery, функции

Здравствуйте. необходимо  зациклить функцию. Т.е. прошла анимация первого дива и после нее он исчезает появляется 2й и после конца его анимации появляется снвоа первый. я понимаю что display:none тут не совсем верно ибо он сразу же его и убивает, но других идей пока нет. var groupName=1; число тестовое решение. ибо в идеале он будет крутить по счетчику i++ пока не дойдет до конца где снова будет равен начальному значению.

```
function a() {
    $('#bl2').css("display", "none");
    $('#bl1').css("display", "block");
    var groupName = 1;

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#bl1').css("display", "none");
        $('#bl2').css("display", "block");
        var groupName = 2;

        $(".animated[data-animation-group=" + groupName + "]").restartAnimation();
        a();
    },4000)
}
a();
```

Ну и кроме того мой недокод жрет память и при долгой работе ложит браузер, кароче одни минусы)подскажите что можете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам только для двух элементов, то можно попробовать что-то вроде этого:

```
function slide() {
    var hiddenElement = $(".block.hide");

    $(".block:not(.hide)").addClass("hide");

    hiddenElement.removeClass("hide").css("opacity", 0).animate({"opacity" : 1}, 600);        
}

setInterval( slide, 3000);
```

Где .block это класс для двух элементов которые будут друг друга менять. A .hide это класс с dispay: none.

Возможно код можно как-то упросить, или оптимизировать. Я по быстрому решение накидал.